# The join density function is the product of the individual density functions?

Tags: statistics

Let $X$ and $Y$ two random variables. Suppose $X$ has density function $f_X$ and $Y$ density function $f_Y$. Is the joint probability density function of $X$ and $Y$ just the multiplication of $f_X f_Y$?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent then yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)\cdot f_Y(y)$. Otherwise $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)⋅f_{Y∣X}(y∣x)$.

Here is an example, where you need the conditional pdf/probablity. Let´s say we have the following joint distribution.
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline X/Y&0 & 1&2 & 3& f_X(x)  \\ \hline 0&\frac{1}{8} &\frac{1}{8} &0 &0 &\frac{2}{8}  \\ \hline 1&0 &\frac{2}{8} &\frac{2}{8} &0&\frac{4}{8} \\ \hline 2&0 &0 &\frac{1}{8} &\frac{1}{8} &\frac{2}{8}  \\ \hline f_Y(y)&\frac{1}{8} &\frac{3}{8} &\frac{3}{8} &\frac{1}{8} &1 \\ \hline \end{array}$$

Here we see, that it is not true that $f_X(x)\cdot f_Y(y)=f_{X,Y}(x,y)$. For instance $X=1, Y=2$

We have $f_X(1)\cdot f_Y(2)=\frac{4}{8}\cdot \frac{3}{8}=\frac{3}{16}$, while $f_{X,Y}(1,2)=\frac{2}{8}=\frac{4}{16} \qquad \color{red}{\times}$

But we have $f_{Y\mid X}(2 \mid 1)=\frac{1}{2}$. Therefore $f_X(1)\cdot f_{Y\mid X}(2 \mid 1)=\frac{4}{8}\cdot \frac12=\frac{4}{16}=\frac{2}{8}=f_{X,Y}(1,2)\qquad \color{limegreen}{\checkmark}$